# How to know which application is using an Assembly in GAC?

Tags: .net, asp.net, assemblies, gac

How to know which application is using an **Assembly** in **GAC**? I want to remove **unwanted** assemblies from **GAC** but it is not getting removed as it is **used** by some other application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to find processes using a file.

Comment: IF some application is using a dll, then that dll is not unwanted.

Comment: And until you figure out which application it is, you'll never know if it is wanted or not. :(  Sadly, Process Explorer only tells you if it is currently loaded in memory, not if it is locked because of a registry entry saying it is "in use" by N applications.

Comment: I often find that ProcessExplorer will not list the applications that are using gac files. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 2):

A passive approach can be using the Visual Studio tool [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28VS.71%29.aspx) to configure logging for all assemblies that are used on your machine. Then later you can examine the log and draw conclusion of which GAC elements are not used.

Comment: Again, this only helps if it is "in use" in memory during your logging time.  It does not help if it is only "in use" because of some count in some registry field saying N application have claimed they are using this DLL.  The Windows architecture can be very annoying.